# Confusing 2N3773 transistor connection

Tags: batteries, transistor-array

We have a battery capacity tester (upto 30V battery & upto 25A discharge current) which when connected to a battery causes a heavy spark even in off condition (Control card supply off).

We have realised that there is some short circuit internally.

I opened the tester and saw a array of 2N3773 transistors connected in parallel as shown in the picture. I see this is the only possibility where it causing short circuit.

[image: Array of transistors connected in parallel]

I am confused to see both incoming (from battery positive - fat red wire) & outgoing (to battery negative - fat black wire) wires are taken from collector (transistor body - as per the datasheet of 2N3773, body is collector).

- How can it be possible?
- Can anyone explain please?
- Doesn't it cause shorting?

The circuit looks like this:

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: What is connected to "incoming?"  What is connected to "outgoing?"

Comment: Positive wire from battery is incoming to transistor array. The outgoing wire is going back to negative terminal of the battery. And the base is connected to current control card

Comment: If you are connecting the thick red wire to B+ and the thick black wire to B-, then the whole thing is one big, fat, short circuit.  You could remove the transistors and it would "work" the same as always.

Comment: But it was working well with the same way of connections. Company has provided us in this way only. Recently it has started causing problems.

Comment: There is a current control card which controls the constant discharge current by driving the base of these transistors. Can you tell me what is the other way to connect so that the current controlling works on these transistors and without short

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone may have replaced a transistor and did not realize that some of the connections are insulated.

I think that the connections to each transistor are as follows.

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgEVvC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Wow, thank you. Good information. Tomorrow I will check this & come back to you.

Comment: Wow! That's indeed the correct answer. Thumbs up,@jsotola, for your excellent observation and inference! However the ingenuity of the builder has been negated by poor wiring/workmanship. Looping of positive and negative connections to the individual transistors is a glaring example of that. Terminating those wires at positive and negative star points would be the right way.

Comment: @jsotola Yes, you are right. Insulation burnt and collector touching the metallic part. We disconnected that particular transistor, now shorting problem sorted out. Thank you.